# jQuery Removing Items From DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my view I have a dropdownlist that uses [Select2](https://select2.org/), a blank `ul` element, and a hidden ListBox Element.  The Listbox element is what is being submitted to the server.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Grade", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.DropDownList("IPGrade", null, "-- Select a Grade --", new { id = "Grade-DDL", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul id="Grade-List" class="list-group"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.LstGrades, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "Grades-ListBox", @class = "form-control" })
```

Now, when the user selects an option from the dropdownlist, that value is being populated into the `ul` element and the Listbox element via jQuery.  When the element is being added to the `ul` element, I am also creating a `btn` that allows the user to remove the item from the `ul` and the Listbox.  Herein lies the problem.

The user has the ability to select the same option in the dropdownlist however many times they choose, so if they select `Option 1` from the dropdownlist 3 times.. then the `ul` element and the Listbox element will have `Option 1` 3 times.  But, if the user selected `Option 1` one too many times and they want to remove one from the `ul` so they are still left with 2 is where my problem is.

When the user tries to remove an option that is repeated in the `ul` element.. when they click remove.. it removes ALL options that are the same as the one that is being repeated.  So in the example above.. if the user tried to delete one of the `Option 1`.. then it will delete all 3 `Option 1`.

Here is my jQuery.

**Adding items to UL and Listbox**

```
$("#Grade-DDL").on("select2:select",
    function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.params);
        $("#Grade-List").append("<li class='list-group-item' data-id='" +
            evt.params.data.id +
            "' >" +
            evt.params.data.text +
            " <input type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs remove-button' style='float: right; margin-top: -2%;' value='x' /></li>");
        $("#Grades-ListBox")
            .append("<option selected='true' value='" +
                evt.params.data.id +
                "'>" +
                evt.params.data.text +
                "</option>");
        $("#Grade-DDL").val("").change();
    });
```

**Removing items from UL and Listbox**

```
function removeGradeCapability() {
    $("#Grade-List").on("click",
        ".remove-button",
        function () {
            //alert($(this).parent().text());
            //alert($(this).parent().data("id"));
            var elementId = $(this).parent().data("id");

            $("#Grades-ListBox option[value='" + elementId + "']").remove(); // remove item from listbox
            $(this).parent().remove(); // remove item from ul element
        });
}
```

**Goal**

Only remove that single option that the user is selecting, even if that option is repeated in the `ul` element...

Any help is appreciated.

**Updated Fiddle**

Here is a replica of what exactly my problem is!

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4o2x5bx/10/)

Comment: You seem to be missing a `]` -- `$("#Grades-ListBox option[value='" + elementId + "']")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sorry, edited

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).find(".list-group-item").data("id")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No I have not.. Is that for removing items from the `ul` or the Listbox.. because removing elements from the `ul` is working fine.. it's just when a user removes a repeated item from the `ul`, the `ul` displays correctly, but in the hidden Listbox is where the repeated item will get removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your options have same values, so sure thing, selecting them by value you'll delete em all,

you need to add some unique identifier to your options, or even better  - add handler to the element right in creation time.

Something like this should work:

```
function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.params);
  $("#Grade-List").append(
    $("<li class='list-group-item' data-id='" + evt.params.data.id + "' >" + evt.params.data.text + " </li>")
        .append(
            $("<input type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs remove-button' style='float: right; margin-top: -2%;' value='x' />")
                .click(function(e){
                    $(e.target).closest('option').remove();
                })
        )
  );
  $("#Grades-ListBox")
    .append("<option selected='true' value='" +
        evt.params.data.id +
        "'>" +
        evt.params.data.text +
        "</option>");
  $("#Grade-DDL").val("").change();
});
```

About ID :

```
var usedIDs = [];
// as a concept only
function generateId() { 
  let id = ('' + (new Date()).getTime() + (1000* Math.random())).replace('.', '');
  return usedIDs.indexOf(id) == -1 ? id : generateId();
}
```

then in your select:

```
let uid = generateId();
$("#Grade-List").append('<li ...tradada ... ' + 'data-uid="' + uid + '"... tradada ... </li>');
$("#Grades-ListBox").append("<option ...tradada ... ' + 'data-uid="' + uid + '"... tradada ... </option>');
```

finaly on delete-click:

```
$('[data-uid="' + $(e.target).data('uid')+ '"]').remove()
```

Comment: This is for removing elements from the `ul`.  Removing elements from the `ul` is working fine.. It's when the user clicks on the remove button in the `ul` it removes ALL of those selections from the Listbox.. My problem deals with the listbox, not the `ul`.. I only want that one selection removed from the listbox, not all repeated items.

Comment: In my question, my problem is under **Removing items from UL and Listbox**.. I need to only remove the one item from the listbox.. the `ul` is working as expected

Comment: sorry, you just have a tone of text)), this void code is totally confusing, I can't guess how it's displaying, can you put it to some fiddle or plunker? all I get that you selecting all "options" with same value, but should delete only one... 

anyway it's not disregarding the points I've mentioned: set uniquer id OR add click handler to element while appending it

Comment: How would I set a unique Id for the Listbox element?  I can't set a click handler to the element in the listbox because the listbox is hidden.

Comment: Creating a fiddle now, hold on

Comment: thats why I'm asking for plunker. I don't understand all your items, when you selecting "something" in "select2:select" you adding same ID and TEXT into 2 elements, correct ? so why not generate some unique id for both of your containers to delete them?

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4o2x5bx/8/).  For some reason, the listbox isn't being populated when I make a selection.. but there it is.

Comment: Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4o2x5bx/10/) Listbox is not getting values appended.

Comment: it's because of case ListBox != Listbox
need to go, I'll check it later, updeted with my thoughts on ID, maybe it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161309/discussion-between-gtown-coder-and-2oppin).